# Placing markers for 6000+ locations using Google Maps (or some other web & mobile platform)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The closest example of what I'm trying to accomplish is a store locator. I have 6,000+ locations that need to be plotted onto a map of Canada.

My original plan was to use Google maps to place markers on each location, but it doesn't make sense to plot them *all* every time someone attempts to view the map, or various parts of the map.

How does one only put markers on the locations in view? Do I have to send the geo data of all 6000 locations to the client each time they load the map?

Is this doable with maps? (I'm sure it's got to be) Or is there a better service for this kind of thing?

Comment: Try clustering your markers http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/11/introduction-to-marker-clustering-with-google-maps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely do not draw all the locations at the same time if they are not all visible. Consider using `MarkerManager` ([article here](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/)) or `MarkerLight` (code: http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/manymarkers/, demo: http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/manymarkers/randommarkers.html). If your initial map and data is such that all the markers would be visible initially, this is definitely the way to go.

You can also use the `GEvent` object ([docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GEvent)) to detect a "move" event, then check the current display coordinates, draw any that are in bounds. This is the best route if your initial map is too zoomed or small, and/or your marker set is too large to fit on the map's initial view. Your user will be moving the map around, so you can react to that movement and only draw the relevant markers. Take a look at http://econym.org.uk/gmap/gevent.htm for a list of other GEvent events (couldn't find an official list on the API), you might also want to watch "zoom" events.

The two methods can also be combined.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getBounds()` to determine the viewable portion of the map.  I'd use this data to request from the server all locations within those bounds.  Use the `bounds_changed` event to monitor changes to the viewport and request additional locations as necessary.  You'll probably want to set either a minimum zoom level, or maximum number of results to avoid displaying too many locations than is reasonable.  Eg, when the map is zoomed out to display all of Canada in a single view.